# XMLHttpRequest url contains (&)

Tags: javascript, php

so I have this code to send data unto the backend

```
var $word = "minds & brains";

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }

xhttp.open("GET", 'http://mywebsite.com/controller/sample_controller?keyword='+$word, true);
xhttp.send();
```

but on my php it only gets the mind

```
<?php

    echo $_GET['keyword'];
```

any ideas, help on how to acquire the exactly word "minds & brains"?

Comment: Spaces and `&`s are unsafe characters in URLs. Use `encodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to escape the `&` character:

```
xhttp.open("GET", 'http://mywebsite.com/controller/sample_controller?keyword='+ encodeURIComponent($word), true);
```

Comment: I've read somewhere that the truly safest encoding is defined in RFC5987 - the code for that is `s => encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/['()]/g, escape).replace(/\*/g, '%2A').replace(/%(?:7C|60|5E)/g, unescape);`

Comment: @JaromandaX I'd be interested to know where you saw that; you'd think that encodeURIComponent would be as safe as it needed to be.

Comment: yeah, me too - I can't recall to be honest, it's been years - I just have that code in a library I wrote (I called the function `rfc5987encode` which is why I remember the rfc :p ) - it's probably something to do with unicode or languages other than English

Answer (score -1):

try usung urlencode($word)

xhttp.open("GET", 'http://mywebsite.com/controller/sample_controller?keyword='+urlencode($word), true);

Comment: where does this `urlencode` function come from? it's not part of javascript

Comment: if you write javascript inside php , you can use this in php

Comment: Not like that you can't